# HTML Table - How do I make all rows expand if one row in a column expands?

Tags: html

So as I explained in the title, I wonder how I make all the rows in my column follow the one row that expands in width. I basically want that when one of the rows start getting wider because of text, the rest of the rows in the same column will follow that width.

It's a simple html table I'm asking help for. All I want is whenever one of my rows in my column start getting wider the rest of the rows that is in the same column will follow the width of the expanding row.

Here's and illustration of what I want to happen in my table:

[image]

```
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr class="item">
      <td>
        <div class="thumbnail">

        </div>  
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="video--channel">Channel name</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="video--name">Vestibulum magna lectus, convallis non ex in, suscipit.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
   <tr class="item">
      <td>
        <div class="thumbnail">

        </div>  
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="video--channel">Channel nameasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsssssssssssssssss</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="video--name">Vestibulum magna lectus, convallis non ex in, suscipit.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
   <tr class="item">
      <td>
        <div class="thumbnail">

        </div>  
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="video--channel">Channel name</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="video--name">Vestibulum magna lectus, convallis non ex in, suscipit.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Have you read the page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: I feel like I've explained my problem, what's confusing to you?

Comment: Can you share code? what did you try so far?

Comment: @Athax Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @reporter I've added the code now, It's a simple html table I'm asking help for. All I've want is whenever one of my rows in my column start getting wider the rest of the rows that is in the same column will follow the width of the expanding row. :)

Comment: it is what happening as per your html, here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLqgoM)

Comment: @JackRyder Apparently display: flex was doing something weird with my table.